# Connecting to ITIS SOLR API via `httr::POST`

Tags: r, post, solr, get, httr

I'm trying to pull some records from the [ITIS SOLR
API](http://www.itis.gov/solr_documentation.html).

My queries will consist of a string of species binomials (e.g., *Gulo
gulo*) that will often stretch beyond the character limit of URLs, thus
making it impractical (impossible?) to use `httr::GET`. As I understand,
`httr::POST`ing does not have this limitation, so that's how I'm trying
to pass my queries.

I'm having trouble making that leap, despite several hours in the `httr`
documentation and various discussions
([e.g.](https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/159)) about the proper
form of the body to pass via `POST`.

Any help is much appreciated...

```
library(httr)
library(solrium)

spp_binom <- c("Sphyrapicus varius", "Odocoileus virginianus")
args <- list(wt = 'json')
body <- list(q = paste0('nameWOInd:(', paste(shQuote(spp_binom), collapse = " "), ')'))
body2 <- list(nameWOInd = paste(shQuote(spp_binom), collapse = " "))

# GET works
tt <- GET("http://services.itis.gov/", 
          query = c(body, args))
tt <- structure(content(tt, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"), 
                class = "sr_search", wt = 'json')
solrium:::solr_parse(tt, parsetype = "df", concat = ",")[, c(1,3,6,12)]

## Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
## 
##      tsn              nameWOInd usage    rank
##    <chr>                  <chr> <chr>   <chr>
## 1 178202     Sphyrapicus varius valid Species
## 2 180699 Odocoileus virginianus valid Species

# POST doesn't
tt <- POST(url="http://services.itis.gov/", encode = "json",
           body = body) # same w/content_type_json()
solrium:::get_response(tt)

## [1] ""

tt <- POST(url="http://services.itis.gov/", encode = "json",
           body = body2) # same w/content_type_json() 
solrium:::get_response(tt)

## [1] ""
```

Answer (score 2):

maintainer of solrium here.  Have you tried using the `ritis` package yet?  https://github.com/ropensci/ritis It has fxns for the ITIS SOLR service as well as the other endpoints.

You can use `ritis::itis_search`

```
spp <- c("Sphyrapicus varius", "Odocoileus virginianus")
query <- paste0(paste0("nameWInd:", sub("\\s", "\\\\%20", spp)), collapse = " OR ")
itis_search(q = query, callopts = verbose())

# A tibble: 2 × 28
     tsn               nameWInd              nameWOInd       unit1       unit2 usage credibilityRating
   <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>       <chr>       <chr> <chr>             <chr>
1 178202     Sphyrapicus varius     Sphyrapicus varius Sphyrapicus      varius valid TWG standards met
2 180699 Odocoileus virginianus Odocoileus virginianus  Odocoileus virginianus valid TWG standards met
# ... with 21 more variables: taxonAuthor <chr>, kingdom <chr>, parentTSN <chr>, rankID <chr>, rank <chr>,
#   hierarchySoFar <chr>, hierarchySoFarWRanks <chr>, hierarchyTSN <chr>, synonyms <chr>,
#   synonymTSNs <chr>, expert <chr>, publication <chr>, otherSource <chr>, vernacular <chr>,
#   jurisdiction <chr>, geographicDivision <chr>, createDate <chr>, updateDate <chr>,
#   hierarchicalSort <chr>, `_version_` <dbl>, comment <chr>
```

Though I imagine you'll still run into URL too long errors with that.

I tried some POST requests to ITIS, and it appears they aren't blocking POST requests, but sending a body with various arrangements don't seem to work. I do have contacts at ITIS, so I can ask how they handle POST requests, and if there is a way to do what you want.

In terms of the length of the URL - that isn't something we can get around. There's simply a max character length for a URL, and you should be getting a 414 error https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

There's also access to ITIS via [taxize](https://github.com/ropensci/taxize) - but I doubt that will help with the URL too long thing.

The best option if you are familiar with SQL might be to just get the ITIS SQL dump http://www.itis.gov/downloads/index.html. If you want an R interface, I maintain [taxizedb](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/taxizedb), which aims to make it easy to download, load into SQL engine locally, then uses `dplyr` to do queries. Let me know if you have any questions about this pkg.

Comment: Thanks @sckott.  I have tried `ritis`.  It's a nice package. :) As you know, `ritis::itis_search` calls `solrium::solr_search` which takes us right back to GET and the 414 error.  If this was intended only for local use, an SQL dump would be the easiest route.  I'd appreciate hearing what ITIS says about POST requests.  In the meanwhile, I've simply chopped the character string (`spp`, in this example) into lengths that guarantee rule-abiding URL lengths and passed them in multiple `solr_search` calls with `lapply`

Comment: I'll let you know what I find out.